# Faster query than distinct in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models

I am using **Django** and **PostgreSQL**, and I have query like below

```
model.objects.filter(field=str(field)).exclude(tr__in=['some','some1']).distinct(
'field1','field2')
```

In my model, I have 1 milion rows. The query above is so slow (It takes around 5-6 secs to fetch). I need alternative and faster way to implement it. Any ideas how to do?

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for this query, the actual SQL query and your data model, including indexes?

Comment: I cant take query because of distinct. But for indexes , yeah there are indexes for 'field' which i used inside of filter in query and another index which not used in query

Comment: I don't understand it, what has "distinct" to do with getting the plain SQL query? Djange creates that query and you can output it on disk or screen. Or ask your database to log the query, that also works fine. Without information, it's gonna be hard to help you.